# Android Library that depends on another Android Library

Tags: android, android-library

All the following are Android Library Projects.
'thirdPartyLibrary'
'module1'
'module2'

With the assumption of 'Android Library thirdPartyLibrary' having a dependency on 'Android Library module1', how do you allow access to submodule functions?

After exporting 'Android Library thirdPartyLibrary' as a .jar for a third party library, public classes of 'Android Library module1' are not available to them.  How do you design the jar exported to provide access to members of the submodule?

Comment: i don't understand your question. there are no particular constraint related to the submodule being a dependency of the module. (possible issue with obfuscating?)

Comment: seems like you designed the (hierarchical) dependency the wrong way - either change the dependency (submodule1 having dependency to module1) or export submodule1 to a jar

Comment: @njzk2 Let's say that as a company there are three Android libraries that we have that perform different tasks, and one Android Library wants to use some of them to re-use that work.  That's the dependency I am trying to understand packaging that sub-library within the overall libraries jar file.

Comment: @Mr.Radar Your suggestion is instead of providing one jar, that the SDK should be distributed in two jars?  That's a solution, but if there are five libraries, its seems odd that one library couldn't be distributed as a single jar instead of five jars that they would have to drop into a libs folder and include when they want to integrate the sdk.

Comment: @JaySnayder Nope, my suggestion is to "turn around" the dependency between the libraries, as the "dependency"-relation is AFAIK not symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

Providing similar package names across Android Libraries allows for classes to communicate with one another with 'default' or 'protected' status.  Even though they are in different projects.  I had not known that this would work across Android libraries.

So, in order to obscure what the user should or shouldn't see within the library when exporting a third party SDK, while still keeping separate functional libraries and providing access across them, the package names just need to be the same.  This required a little bit of re-factoring but in the end 'module1' can share its protected classes with 'thirdPartyLibrary'.

'module1' is a dependency for 'thirdPartyLibrary' directly as a Library Project in the settings.
'module2' is a dependency for 'thirdPartyLibrary' directly as a Library Project in the settings.
'thirdPartyLibrary' gets exported as a jar library and passed to the end-user.